# returning multiple class model data from linq in list via return method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have LINQ output which I am trying to pass in list but I am getting following error 
[image]

in linq result I am trying to pass data from two class model, if I do one class model (listOfCoursesWithoutURL ) then it work but I need to pass processedCourseInstance. I have created ModelView of two classes but not sure what I am missing in this picture

### ViewModel

```
public class CoursesInstanceStudyLevel_ViewModel
{
    public CourseInstanceModel _CourseInstanceModel { get; set; }
    public StudyLevelModel  _StudyLevelModel { get; set; }
}
```

### My Class

```
 public List<CoursesInstanceStudyLevel_ViewModel> ProcessAllCoursesApplicationURL(CourseApplicationsURLFeed_Model _obj)
    {

   using(var _uof = new Courses_UnitOfWork())
    {
    _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll();

     var _listOfCoursesWithoutURL = (from b in ListOfCoursesInstances 
                                           where b.ApplicationURL == null
                                           select b).ToList();


    var processedCourseInstance = (from _courseInstances in _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll()
                                         join _courses in _uof.Courses_Repository.GetAll() on _courseInstances.CourseID equals _courses.CourseID 
                                         join _studylevel in _uof.StudyLevel_Repository.GetAll() on _courses.StudyLevelId equals _studylevel.StudyLevelID
                                         orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
                                         select new { _courseInstances, _studylevel }).ToList();


  return processedCourseInstance;     // it doesn't work ... refer to screen shot
  // return _listOfCoursesWithoutURL //it works 
 }
}
```

### Error

[image]

Comment: i know that but how???

Comment: `select new  CoursesInstanceStudyLevel_ViewModel { } `

Comment: I believe I need to create instance of each classes in linq--> select new {....

Comment: Side note:  the standard is to use PascalCase for naming public members without leading underscores. Your properties should be named `CourseInstanceModel` instead of `_CourseInstanceModel`.

Comment: The same goes for `_uof` and `_listOfCoursesWithoutURL` which are local variables and should be called `uof` and `listOfCoursesWithoutURL` instead. Some people prefix *private fields* with an underscore, but never public members of local variables.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With highlighted line in following code snippet, you are selecting an anonymous object instead of a concrete CourseIntaceStudyLeve_ViewModel

> select new { _courseInstances, _studylevel }

You will have to change your query to following..

```
var processedCourseInstance = (from _courseInstances in _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll()
                                             join _courses in _uof.Courses_Repository.GetAll() on _courseInstances.CourseID equals _courses.CourseID 
                                             join _studylevel in _uof.StudyLevel_Repository.GetAll() on _courses.StudyLevelId equals _studylevel.StudyLevelID
                                             orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
                                             select new CoursesInstanceStudyLevel_ViewModel(){
     _CourseInstanceModel  = _courseInstances.FirstOrDefault(),
     StudyLevelModel  = _studylevel.FirstOrDefault()}).ToList();
```

I have assumed you would need only first course and first study level based on your view model definition and there for applied FirstOrDefault. You can choose to go along with this or change your view model definition.

Comment: no I need the whole list i.e. all the courses and their studylevel

Comment: then change you view model property definition to List<CourseInstanceModel> and List<StudyLevelModel> and then remove FirstOrDefault. Although your error is related to anonymous object creation. You are creating anonymous object and trying to return it as a concrete object which is wrong.

Comment: OP doesn't need to do anything other than use his named type.  He's already got `ToList` at the end, it's all good

Answer (score 2):

here:

```
select new { _courseInstances, _studylevel })
```

you are defining an anonymous object.  You have a type ready, so use that one:

```
select new CoursesInstanceStudyLevel_ViewModel 
{ 
      _CourseInstanceModel = _courseInstances, 
      _StudyLevelModel = _studylevel 

}
```

assuming `CourseInstanceModel` and `StudyLevelModel` are the correct types

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer and it works

```
 var processedCourseInstance = 
   (from _courseInstances in _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll()
             join _courses in _uof.Courses_Repository.GetAll() on _courseInstances.CourseID equals _courses.CourseID 
             join _studylevel in _uof.StudyLevel_Repository.GetAll() on _courses.StudyLevelId equals _studylevel.StudyLevelID
             orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
                select new CoursesInstanceStudyLevel_ViewModel() {
                          _CourseInstanceModel = _courseInstances, 
                          _StudyLevelModel  = _studylevel 
                       }).ToList();
```